# new to bash need help with script of dates

Tags: bash, date

I am learning bash scripting and need to get last 30 days from now.

I know it's a dumb script but somehow i am missing something.

I need to display the last 30 days, here is how i do it:

```
#!/bin/bash


for ((i=0 ; i <= 30; i++))
do

z=`date --date='-i day'|awk '{print $2,$3}'`;

echo $z;

done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running `date --date='-i day'`, but you want to use your `$i` variable. You also need double and not single quotes, to make sure the cariable is expanded. Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0 ; i <= 30; i++))
do
    z=`date --date="-$i day"|awk '{print $2,$3}'`;
    echo "$z";
done
```

And, since you're learning, here's a simpler way:

```
$ for i in {0..30}; do date -d "-$i days" +'%b %d'; done
Nov 16
Nov 15
Nov 14
Nov 13
Nov 12
Nov 11
Nov 10
Nov 09
Nov 08
Nov 07
Nov 06
Nov 05
Nov 04
Nov 03
Nov 02
Nov 01
Oct 31
Oct 30
Oct 29
Oct 28
Oct 27
Oct 26
Oct 25
Oct 24
Oct 23
Oct 22
Oct 21
Oct 20
Oct 19
Oct 18
Oct 17
```

Comment: damn those double quotes ...big thx to you :)

Comment: @VitalikJimbei the problem wasn't only the quotes, you also need the `$i` when referring to the variable unless you're in arithmetical context (as inside `(( ))` parentheses).  That said, if this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @VitalikJimbei, note that you don't need awk at all: read the `date` man page and learn the output formatting codes.

Comment: this is a part of a bigger bash script, i was using the date as variable but  could not get it on a loop, i intentionally used the awk to extract what i needed. THX one more time for solving my dilemma :)